# When adding SQL results to a List of objects, all the records get overwritten by the most recent result

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have came across a problem when trying to fetch results from an SQL query into a list of objects in C#. For some reason, it overwrites all rows with the most recent query result and I can't see what I am doing wrong. The Console.WriteLine for testing returns correct data so the query runs fine.

My code is:

```
private void getData(string qry)
  {
      int count = 0;
      string strProject = "ARTUR-PC\\SQLEXPRESS"; //Enter your SQL server instance name
      string strDatabase = "Northwind"; //Enter your database name
      string strUserID = "Artlemaks"; // Enter your SQL Server User Name
      string strPassword = "rootUser"; // Enter your SQL Server Password
      string strconn = "data source=" + strProject +
        ";Persist Security Info=false;database=" + strDatabase +
        ";user id=" + strUserID + ";password=" +
        strPassword + ";Connection Timeout = 0";
      //conn = new SqlConnection(strconn);
      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strconn))
      {
          List<CustomerObj> Customers = new List<CustomerObj>();
          connection.Open();
          SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
          cmd.CommandText = qry;

          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          if (reader.HasRows)
          {
              while (reader.Read())
              {
                  row.custID = reader[0] as int?;
                  row.cmpName = reader[1] as string;
                  row.cntName = reader[2] as string;
                  row.cntTitle = reader[4] as string;
                  row.address = reader[5] as string;
                  row.city = reader[3] as string;
                  row.region = reader[6] as string;
                  row.postalCode = reader[7] as string;
                  row.country = reader[8] as string;
                  row.phone = reader[9] as string;
                  row.fax = reader[10] as string;
                  Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader[0],  reader[1]);

                  Customers.Add(row);
              }

          }
          reader.Close();
          connection.Close();

      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `row` is a global variable defined outside of the function.  If that's the case, you are always using the same row instance over and over again, since the row is a reference type.

Define the row inside the while loop, so your code should become something like this:

```
private void getData(string qry)
  {
      int count = 0;
      string strProject = "ARTUR-PC\\SQLEXPRESS"; //Enter your SQL server instance name
      string strDatabase = "Northwind"; //Enter your database name
      string strUserID = "Artlemaks"; // Enter your SQL Server User Name
      string strPassword = "rootUser"; // Enter your SQL Server Password
      string strconn = "data source=" + strProject +
        ";Persist Security Info=false;database=" + strDatabase +
        ";user id=" + strUserID + ";password=" +
        strPassword + ";Connection Timeout = 0";
      //conn = new SqlConnection(strconn);
      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strconn))
      {
          List<CustomerObj> Customers = new List<CustomerObj>();
          connection.Open();
          SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
          cmd.CommandText = qry;

          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          if (reader.HasRows)
          {
              while (reader.Read())
              {
                  CustomerObj row = new CustomerObj();
                  row.custID = reader[0] as int?;
                  row.cmpName = reader[1] as string;
                  row.cntName = reader[2] as string;
                  row.cntTitle = reader[4] as string;
                  row.address = reader[5] as string;
                  row.city = reader[3] as string;
                  row.region = reader[6] as string;
                  row.postalCode = reader[7] as string;
                  row.country = reader[8] as string;
                  row.phone = reader[9] as string;
                  row.fax = reader[10] as string;
                  Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader[0],  reader[1]);

                  Customers.Add(row);
              }

          }
          reader.Close();
          connection.Close();

      }
```

Comment: I took a quick smoke break and came to the same conclusion... Works perfectly, thank you for confirming my thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same `row` object instance everywhere, so the values are set only on this object instance. Instead you need to initialize a new instance of the class to hold a new result it in each loop iteration.

To fix the issue change

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    row.custID = reader[0] as int?;
```

to

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    CustomerObj row = new CustomerObj();
    row.custID = reader[0] as int?;
```

and remove `row` declaration from where you declare it.